# Как сделать переадресацию на другую страницу после отдачи файла на загрузку?

Tags: php

Есть ссылка `<a href="download.php">Скачать</a>`.

Код файла **download.php**:

```
$filename = 'VCru.URL';

header("Content-type: application/x-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
readfile($filename);

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        location = 'success.html';  
    });
</script>";
```

Как сделать перенаправление на другую страницу после отдачи файла на загрузку? JS-скрипт не срабатывает. И при нажатии на "Скачать" даже не происходит переадресация на download.php. Просто начинает скачиваться файл.

Comment: window.location.href= 'success.html';

Comment: Хотя нужно сделать наоборот. Показать success.html  и на этой странице дать ссылку на скачиваемый файл и сделать window.location.href на файл.

Comment: location.href на файл сделать нельзя, так как файл открывается в браузере. Поэтому отдаем на загрузку через php.

Comment: Хотя я наверное вас неправильно понял. window.location.href на download.php попробую.

Comment: Ваш вариант также не подходит. Так как если обновить страницу success.html, то опять файл скачается.

Comment: Так генерируйте новую ссылку каждый раз. Вообще даже у microsoft при обновлении страницы повторяется загрузка файла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

например так

```
$filename = 'VCru.URL';

header("Content-type: application/x-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
readfile($filename);

header( 'Location: http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=redirect', true, 301 );
```

Comment: Также как и мой вариант, не работает.